# c# DateTime class deep configuration

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

Is there a way to tell DateTime in .net that the day is say, 17 hours instead of 24?  Let's say I'm moving to another planet and I want to write a calendar program (I actually have a earthly reason for asking this).  Am I stuck with 86400 seconds for things to turnover or can I set it to something else?

Comment: Depends on which planet you moved..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In .NET the [`DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) structure is designed to work with human's understanding of time where days have 24 hours, an hour has 60 minutes and a minute has 60 seconds.

If you need some alien time where a day has say 17 hours then you should write your own class for handling this. Unfortunately the .NET framework doesn't provide classes for working with any possible extraterrestrial intelligence understanding of time.

Comment: Who's talking about "extraterrestrial intelligence understanding of time?" http://www.cnn.com/2013/12/10/tech/innovation/mars-one-plan/

Comment: I guess you are the one talking about it. In my answer I just talked about what's built in .NET and what does the `DateTime` structure provide you. Unfortunately it cannot be modified to fit your requirements. This structure simply isn't designed for this purpose. But you could always write your own class to accommodate the specific requirements.